# 'We are starting class now' or 'We are the starting class now'?

Tags: articles, definite-article

I saw the sentence: 'We are starting class now' in a book of English grammar exercises.

But, I don't understand why the sentence has no article (the), like:
'We are starting the class now'.

Comment: [why the sentence does not have]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment

Comment: I was correcting your grammar: "why the sentence doesn't have x" or "why the sentence has no x" and not: why the sentence have no article. Learning how to pose questions correctly is important.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm still learning English :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is simply an idiom, a less formal way of saying "We are starting the class now."

"We are starting class now." assumes that the people now which specific class ('the' definite article) is being described.

I  think it is more commonly used in American english than UK english.